# AMD Optane alternative

Tags: swap, pci-express, nvme, swapping, zfs-l2arc

I want to have an Optane features with my Ryzen build: high TBW and high I/O. Disk space irrelevant (like MEMPEK1W064GA, 64GB would be enough for me). And it would be nice if I can utilize the full power of my free PCIe 4.0 lane. Now I have an PCIe 3.0 x4 NVMe 0.5TB main disk and that's enough for my data, but with Optane-like disk I can speed up caches (Swap / L2ARC / ZIL / pagefile.sys / etc.) and don't torture limited resource of my current disk. What can I use?

Yes, I know that Optane is full hardware feature (not only PCIe, but also chipset and CPU). But anyway...

Comment: No fact-base answer could be provided without knowing your specific requirements (or, say, why you do not simply plug in another healthy chunk of RAM). And even then,  [plain **product recommendations** are off topic here](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @anx what you think - questions about Optane is questions about product or about technology? Another chunk of RAM isn't polymorphic solution - I want to slow down processes which limited by RAM with cgroups but can use swap anyway. I want to use RAM by processes which I want to speed up.